# How can I use summarise to get data from multiple columns using the calculation made only on one of the columns?

Tags: r

I have data about newborn weight measurements in their first year of life:

```
Children <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
age_days = c(0,12,25,33,38,2,25,38,45,18,38,40,60,1,5,10,20), 
weight = c(3.4,3.5,4.5,5.1,5.3,2.8,4.5,5.3,5.6,3.6,5.4,5.5,6.8,3.1,3.0,3.3,4.1))
```

I want to create a table where for each child ID I have measurements at 2 weeks and 1 month. 
Since most children don't have a measurement at exactly 2 weeks or one month, I want to select the measurement which is the closest to the age I need.

I created new variables which calculate the absolute distance from the age measurement I need:

```
Children <- mutate(Children, dis_2weeks = abs(14-age_days), dis_1month = abs(30-age_days))
```

Now I want to create a table which would have for each child the data about the closest measurement to the age I specified (distance in days from desired age and the weight at that measurement). 
It would look approximately like this:

```
  ID dis_2weeks weight_2weeks dis_1month weight_1month
1  1          2           3.5          3           5.1
2  2         11           4.5          5           4.5
3  3          4           3.6          8           5.4
4  4          4           3.3         10           4.1
```

I have tried using the summarise function, but I can't seem to find a way to get the weights using it

`Children %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(dis_2weeks = min(dis_2weeks), dis_1month = min(dis_1month))`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution but this works

```r
library(tidyverse)
Children <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                       age_days = c(0,12,25,33,38,2,25,38,45,18,38,40,60,1,5,10,20), 
                       weight = c(3.4,3.5,4.5,5.1,5.3,2.8,4.5,5.3,5.6,3.6,5.4,5.5,6.8,3.1,3.0,3.3,4.1))
Children <- mutate(Children, dis_2weeks = abs(14-age_days), dis_1month = abs(30-age_days))

# Find two-week and one-month weights for a single child
best_weights = function(df) {
  ix_2weeks = which.min(df$dis_2weeks)
  ix_1month = which.min(df$dis_1month)
  tibble(dis_2weeks=df$dis_2weeks[ix_2weeks],
         weight_2weeks = df$weight[ix_2weeks],
         dis_1month=df$dis_1month[ix_1month],
         weight_1month = df$weight[ix_1month]
         )
}

Children %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(new_data = map(data, best_weights)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest('new_data')
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID dis_2weeks weight_2weeks dis_1month weight_1month
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1     1          2           3.5          3           5.1
#> 2     2         11           4.5          5           4.5
#> 3     3          4           3.6          8           5.4
#> 4     4          4           3.3         10           4.1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::summarize` will give you summary statistics for the variables you feed it, so asking it for `min(dis_2weeks)` will tell you what the minimum value of `dis_2weeks` is, but won't tell you which observation has it.

There are a few straightforward ways to do this. The easiest is probably to `dplyr::arrange()` the data and then use `dplyr::summarize()` to pick the first item:

```
library(dplyr)

Children <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                       age_days = c(0,12,25,33,38,2,25,38,45,18,38,40,60,1,5,10,20), 
                       weight = c(3.4,3.5,4.5,5.1,5.3,2.8,4.5,5.3,5.6,3.6,5.4,5.5,6.8,3.1,3.0,3.3,4.1))

just_minimum <- Children %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(dis_2weeks = abs(14-age_days), dis_1month = abs(30-age_days)) %>%
  arrange(dis_2weeks) %>%
  summarize_all(first)

just_minimum
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     ID age_days weight dis_2weeks dis_1month
  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1       12    3.5          2         18
2     2       25    4.5         11          5
3     3       18    3.6          4         12
4     4       10    3.3          4         20
```

If you want something a little more flexible, instead of using summarize you can use `dplyr::filter()`:

```
just_min2 <- Children %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(dis_2weeks = abs(14-age_days), dis_1month = abs(30-age_days)) %>%
  filter(dis_2weeks == min(dis_2weeks))
just_min2
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID age_days weight dis_2weeks dis_1month
  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1       12    3.5          2         18
2     2       25    4.5         11          5
3     3       18    3.6          4         12
4     4       10    3.3          4         20
```

You might also consider `mutate_subset` in the `pmdplyr` package.

Comment: Additional notes: If you're using the filter() version, make sure that the variable you're using it with doesn't have precision/rounding issues such that the min() doesn't match any actual value - you can check this by making sure all the IDs made it to the just_min version. Also, the mutate_subset suggestion is for if the real goal is to take those ID-specific weights and fill in all those ID's rows of the original data with them.